# Snapkit Layout issue - UITextView going beyond UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextview, snapkit

Using snapkit, I got the image below. **The text view is going over the pop up view and the "List Name" pop up title is more than 10px above the text view.** How to fix?

[image]

**Code**

```
private func makePopUpTitle() {
        popUpTitle.text = "List Name"
        popUpView.addSubview(popUpTitle)

        popUpTitle.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.centerX.equalTo(popUpView)
            make.top.equalTo(popUpView).offset(20)
        }

    }

private func makeListNameTextView() {
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        popUpView.addSubview(nameTextView)

        nameTextView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.left.equalTo(popUpView).offset(20)
            make.right.greaterThanOrEqualTo(popUpView).offset(20)
            make.top.equalTo(popUpTitle.snp.bottom).offset(10)
            make.width.lessThanOrEqualTo(popUpView.snp.width)
            make.height.equalTo(35)
            make.centerY.equalTo(popUpView)
        }
    }
```

Comment: your right constraint is conflicting like             make.right.greaterThanOrEqualTo(popUpView).offset(20). Remove your right constraint or add a constant right constraint as you added in case of left constraint will solve the problem.

Comment: you can try             make.right.greaterThanOrEqualTo(popUpView).offset(-20)

Comment: @coreDeviOS thanks that worked!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like the comments said:

`make.right.greaterThanOrEqualTo(popUpView).offset(-20)`

Comment: downvoted as an answer shouldnt be ONLY a line of code. add comment as to WHY this is the answer :)